# Can not browse for next badge to earn

Tags: bug, badges, badge-progress

Screen tells you it's showing 100 of whatever badges, but none of them show. This functionality used to work.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to disable responsiveness?

Comment: You've obviously earned them all! :-) (Yes, that means there is only 1 gold badge available. Don't know how anyone gets more.)